# How to revert snapshot in VmWare with Terraform?

Tags: terraform, vmware, vsphere, esxi, hcl

I want to use `Terraform` to revert few snapshots.

I've checked [HCL Documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/vsphere/r/virtual_machine_snapshot.html), but I cannot find anything about `revert/restore` snapshots.

My questions are:

- It is possible to restore snapshots, or I can only create them?
- How can I restore snapshots by using `Terraform` ?

Answer (score 0):

This type of activity is not supported through Terraform. For additional information and clarification, here's the discussion where that decision was made: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-vsphere/pull/107#issuecomment-327001399